# c# datatable to csv export

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

Could somebody please tell me why the following code is not working. The data is saved into the CSV file, however, I need to exempt the first two columns.

```cs
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    string[] fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray();
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
}
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Desktop\test.csv", sb.ToString());
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is missing in those 3 answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    IEnumerable<object> fields = row.ItemArray.Skip(2);
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
}
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Desktop\test.csv", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: How will I pass this var x to sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
I am getting error when I change fields to x.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I just wrote down all your code lines with the skip-2, instead of just the changed line.

Comment: How can I add column with values in between, lets say if I want to add a column with values at second last place in table columns

Comment: `List<object> fields = row.ItemArray.Skip(2).ToList();`

`fields.Insert(fields.Count - 2, "inserted column");`

Comment: What if I want to skip last 2 columns can you please advise ?

Comment: int itemCount = row.ItemArray.Count(); List<object> fields = row.ItemArray.Take(itemCount - 2).ToList();
fields.Insert(fields.Count, "inserted column");

Answer (score 0):

```
DataColumn[] unwantedColumns = { table.Column1, ... };

var x = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                       .Except(unwantedColumns)
                       .Select(c => row.Field<int>(c))
```

Comment: This won't help me as I my table is always and it only gets populated during run time, How can I specify column names in unwanted columns, when I don't know until table is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple

```
var fields = row.ItemArray.Skip(2);
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
```

Comment: What if I want to skip last 2 columns can you please advise ?